# Variable in PHP iterates through an SQL result and not

Tags: php, mysqli

I have to made a page with multiple pictures that I get from database and for each picture I have a button that add that picture in a database table. All goods, but when I press a button for a random image will it add only first image that I get from database.
Here is the code:

```
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
    echo 'SQL ERROR';
} else {
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo '<li style="text-align:center;background:rgba(255,255,255,0.4); color:black;border:1px solid black;margin:0.5em;">

        <p>' .$row['title'] .'</p>
        <div style="background:white;"><img src="images/' . $row["imgFullName"] . '"> <img src="images/' . $row["reversePic"] . '"></div>
        <p>Value: ' . $row['value'] . '</p>
        <p>Country: ' . $row['country'] . '</p>
        <p>Created at: ' . $row['createdAt'] . '</p> 
        <p class="wrapword">' . $row['description'] . '</p>';
       if ($_SESSION['username'] != "admin") { 
                echo '<form method="POST" id= "insert">
                <button type="button" class="btn-inventory" name="submit-inventory" data-id="'.$row['id'].'" >Add</button></form></li>';

            }
        }
    }
} 
?>
```

Also the button works with AJAX. The problem is that *data-id* attribute gets only first id.

**EDIT:**
Here is the js code:

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
              $(".btn-inventory").click(function(){
                 var coin_id = $('.btn-inventory').attr("data-id");
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "../Includes/insert.php",
                            method: "post",
                            data: {coin: coin_id},
                            success: function(response){
                                alert(response);
                            }
                        });
                      });
                 });
       </script>
```

Comment: `if ($_SESSION['username'] == "admin") {} elseif ($_SESSION['username'] != "admin") ` are you serious?

Comment: Also, where's js code that performs ajax?

Comment: @u_mulder I'm sorry for that, now i fixed it. Also i added the js.

Comment: `var coin_id = $(this).attr("data-id");`

Comment: @u_mulder thank you very much <3 love you man